# I can find the service I want in k8, but I don't know its pod name, how can I find out the pod name of the service?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I can get the service using k get svc, but I don't know which pod it lives, I can't tell it from the pod names I have, how can I find out the related pod of my service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a service you also define the selector for the particular service.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376
```

In this example my-service defines selector as  `app:MyApp`
This service will look for a pod with the same label selector.
The controller for the Service selector continuously scans for Pods that match its selector, and then POSTs any updates to an Endpoint object also named “my-service”.
You can get the list of Pods this service is routing traffic to
`kubectl get po -l app:MyApp`
If you are not getting any pod with this command then its obvious that the service is not able to find any pod that contains the label selector.
And yes services can exist without Pods as well.See [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)

Answer (score 1):

A service selects pods by using the label selector. So you can list the pods which has label matching the label in the selector of the service.

```
kubectl get pods -l=app=tea
NAME                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
tea-5b6c494c68-b4n7t   1/1     Running   0          2d17h
```

Comment: the command result tells me that no resources found. Is it possible that the service exists but the pod doesn't?